# Hide vs Remove DOM elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, optimization

### Hide vs Remove

What is the best way to handle DOM elements, hide or delete?. assume that the environment can change several times. Elements can have click-callbacks or other event callback.

**Hide**

When hide what is best?. If clicking a button hide multiple items, you can hide one by one or you can also create css rules to do so.

*Option 1:*

```
<style>
.superContent{/*...*/}

.superContent.noEdit .occultable{
    display:none;
}
</style>

<form class=”superContent” action=”...”>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type=”text” />
    <input type=”submit” class=”occultable” value=”send”/>
</form>

<button id=”hideAll”>Edit</button>
<script type=”text/javascript”>
    $(“#hideAll”).click(function(){
        $(“.superContent”).toggleClass(“noEdit”);
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/p8mU8/

The other option is to just hide the desired items (these may be few or many):

*Option 2:*

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
    $(“#hideAll”).click(function(){
        $(“.occultable”).toggle();
    });
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JAmF9/

---

**Remove**

To modify the DOM you can also delete unwanted items and re-insert them later.

*Option 3:*

```
<form class="superContent">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" />
    <input id="sendbutton" type="submit" class="occultable" value="send"/>
</form>

<button id="hideAll">Edit</button>​

<script type=”text/javascript”>
$("#hideAll").click(function(){
    if( $(".superContent").find("#sendbutton").length>0 ){
        $(".superContent").find("#sendbutton").remove();
    }
    else{
        $(".superContent").append('<input id="sendbutton" type="submit" class="occultable" value="send"/>');
    }
});​
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Yj5Aw/

These are just small examples. Assuming a UI that contains a large number of elements. What do you think the best option?. Which has less memory leak and more performance?

There are some javascript frameworks like kendo-ui that removes elements.
jQueryUI prefers to hide items, but the widget Tab sortable creates the tab temporarily dragged by the user.

Comment: If you don't want to display the element later use `remove`, otherwise use `addClass` and `removeClass` to hide/show the element.

Comment: I like hiding elements if I plan on showing them again in the future. In my opinion, it will not produce unexpected results to the UI as easily as recreating it.

Answer (score 24):

It's kind of obvious you know

- Hide is the best when you want to re-show the elements.
- Remove is the best when you won't need to use the elements again.

When you hide elements and then re-show them those elements don't lose all their callback and data, specially when jQuery is in use.

When you remove unnecessary elements, you reduce the memory allocated for your page, though in most scenarios it won't be a significant change.

Comment: Creating a css rule to show/hide elements should be quicker than manipulating properties through javascript. I think there was a test showing this on quirksmode.org

Comment: This doesn't really answers the questions.. lets say I can show 3 different tables of data, each has *thousands* of rows. I switch between the tables using some tabs navigation. question is, does it matter if the DOM has thousands of nodes, even though the table has `display:none` for non-active tabs? does it create some sort of slowness of any kind? that should be answered. events will not be removed even if you remove the element, if one know *any basic* jQuery one would use `detach` and not `remove` for that.

Comment: How does this apply with tooltip popups on hover for various portions of my application? Should I always add/remove the tooltip nested under that currently hovered element, or add a single `tooltip` element to the page and position / show that where needed @gdoron

Comment: Now (6 years after the question was asked) the main frameworks in frontend (Angular, React, Vue) use the strategy of remove/create, although now we are talking about destroying components, not only DOM.

Comment: I've created a simple benchmark on this to compare performance of both cases: https://www.measurethat.net/Benchmarks/Show/14104/0/create-and-appendremove-versus-displayblockdisplaynone